# How can I bind an Event to changing the property on another element in the tree in XAML WPF?

Tags: wpf, events, xaml

I'll start off with the code as it should be fairly self-explanatory:

```
<commonControls:SearchTextBox
                    x:Name="searchTextBox"
                    Margin="6,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    MinWidth="50"
                    Width="130"
                    SearchMode="Instant"
                >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Search">
                            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Search}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=searchTextBox, Path=Text}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Cancel">
                            <!-- Code to set searchTextBox.Text to Empty -->
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </commonControls:SearchTextBox>
```

The `SearchTextBox` has an Event called `Cancel` which executes if the user clicks the X button on the right hand side of the TextBox. What I would like to do is hook onto that event, and clear the Text property of the TextBox. I'm looking for a way to do this purely in XAML, with no Code Behind, and without hitting the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a concept called 'attached behaviours', attached properties that on attachment handle events on the target object and perform some action as a result. See the following article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx

I see you are already using blend interactions. Blend provides a simple framework for behaviours making them easier to implement, you simple override the `OnAttach` method to add your logic. See the example here:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/06/metro-in-motion-part-7-panorama-prettiness-and-opacity/

Comment: I'm not actually using Blend. I'm using Mvvm Light, which requires System.Windows.Interactivity to take care of the EventToCommand. I'll have a look at those links now though, thanks.

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more simple unfortunately. Though this is the correct answer, I'll probably just wire it up in code-behind since it is a one line job and doesn't need to be reusable.